# Inetmgr.exe not recognized as command

Tags: windows, iis, windows-7, asp.net, asp

On my Windows 7 machine, I've just installed IIS and it should work, but doesn't!

Well, finding it anyway... and when I run inetmgr.exe the command prompt doesn't recognize it.

```
C:\Windows\system32>inetmgr.exe
'inetmgr.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What should I do to fix this to ensure IIS works properly?
Also, the IIS Manager doesn't appear in the start menu.

Should I re-install it from scratch?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

`inetmgr.exe` is in `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv`, which isn't in the system `PATH`.  So do a `cd inetsrv` first.

In your start menu search, type in 'IIS'.  If it doesn't show, then it sounds like it's not fully installed for some reason.  Going through the installer again will hopefully resolve that.